# Modify spark DataFrame column

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe

I would like to change the following dataframe:

```
--id--rating--timestamp--
-------------------------
| 0 | 5.0  |  231312231 |
| 1 | 3.0  |  192312311 | #Epoch time (seconds from 1 Thursday, 1 January 1970)
-------------------------
```

to the following dataframe:

```
--id--rating--timestamp--
--------------------------
| 0 |  5.0  |  05        |
| 1 |  3.0  |  04        | #Month of year
--------------------------
```

How I can do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's easy using built-in functions

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._;
import spark.implicits._
val newDF = dataset.withColumn("timestamp", month(from_unixtime('timestamp)));
```

Note that DataFrames are immutable, so you can create new DataFrame but not modify. Of course you can assign this Dataset to the same variable.

Note number 2: DataFrame = Dataset[Row], that's why I use both names

Comment: what if i want to get the current column and add some value to that column by each row and update the column row ?

Answer (score 1):

If you coming from scala, you can use [`sql.functions`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) methods inside `Dataframe.select` or `Dataframe.withClumn` methods, for your case I think the method `month(e: Column): Column` can perform the change you want. It will be something like that :

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.month
df.withColumn("timestamp", month("timestamp") as "month")
```

I do believe that there's an equivalent way in `Java`, `Python` and `R`